# Database Schema Question

Tags: database, schema

I am having problem understanding how merged schema works. If I have two tables from two discrete database systems

```
Company A
work (work_ID, name, job_type, place, salary)

Company B
job (job_ID, name, work_type, net_Value)
```

How can I create a merged schema?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use both tables in the same scheme?

Comment: @sikas: Yes, I am trying to merge them together so that I can access the data from both

Comment: is there a mapping between the 2 tables? By mapping I mean, which attribute in CompanyA table maps to which attribute in CompanyB table. It will be helpful if you edit to answer to specify this mapping information.

Comment: one simple way is to create a many-to-many relation using a middle table, that is creating a table named, for example, work_job and the table can contain work_ID and job_ID which are linked back to work and job respectively.

Answer (score 1):

create view jobs as

select
work_ID as job_ID, name, job_type as work_type, place, salary as net_Value from CompanyA.work A
union all
select
job_ID,           name, work_type,  "Unknown Place",    net_Value from CompanyB.job B

may need () around the contents of the selects depending on the db.

Comment: union all won't work like this as the number of columns provided in the two selects are different.